# Django save ManyToManyField Model with ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, modelmultiplechoicefield

So I know there are a few similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me. I've tried save(commit=false) and save_m2m as well as a bunch of other stuff but i get the error

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: home_services.managers_id
```

Anyways here's my code:
views.py

```
def service(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':    #Create Service
            form = CreateServiceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/service')     #Later change this to redirect to server page
        else:
            form = CreateServiceForm()
            args = {'user': request.user, 'form': form}
            return render(request, 'service.html', args)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/feed')
```

models.py

```
class Services(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    managers = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="managers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ": id" + str(self.id)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Services
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
            'owner',
            'members',
        ]
```

I want the user to be able to create a service and select 1 or more members that is in the default django User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user to be able to create a service and select 1 or more members that is in the default django User model.

You are not providing `managers`, which is not allowed as per the current configuration.

So, change:

```
managers = models.ForeignKey(
    User, 
    related_name="managers", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

To:

```
managers = models.ForeignKey(
    User, 
    related_name="managers", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

You might want to read more about [blank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#blank) and [null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#null).

Comment: thanks alot. I then did:

form.save(commit=False)
form.save()
form.save_m2m()

and everything worked!